# Is it possible for the Amortentia Potion to smell like a loved one/relative?

Tags: harry-potter

I know Amortentia is a sort of love potion, but would it be possible for it to smell like a loved one/relative? Or is it just based off of crushes, whether known or unknown by an individual?

I’ve read into it, and even seen some posts/headcanons about it, so I was thinking that it would only smell like a crush (if you’d call it that). But, I’m still curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smell of Amortentia is described by Hermione in the first Potions class in *Half-Blood Prince*:

> "And the steam rising in characteristic spirals," said Hermione
>   enthusiastically, "and it's supposed to smell differently to each of
>   us, according to what attracts us, and I can smell freshly mown grass
>   and new parchment and –"

So it would probably depend on whether the person is "attracted" to their loved one/relative. Hermione smells grass and parchment, neither of which is the subject of the type of love for a crush (I think), so it is reasonable to assume that the potion could account for other forms of attraction as well.

Indeed, Harry too smells things besides for his crush, as we see in the same scene:

> Somehow it reminded him simultaneously of treacle tart, the woody
>   smell of a broomstick handle and something flowery he thought he might
>   have smelled at The Burrow.

So there does not seem to be a reason why it couldn't also smell like a loved one/relative that one is attracted to, even though it is not a crush.

Comment: This is just speculation of course, but "freshly mown grass" for Hermione and "smell of a broomstick" for Harry made me think of their respective fathers.

Comment: @TenthJustice The smell of broomstick must surely be Harry's own, right? Harry never smelled his father's broom unless he was very young (and the broom might have been destroyed with their house after Voldemort attacked). As for Hermione, [we don't know why she smells grass](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131062/82909).

Comment: Regarding "something flowery he thought he might have smelled at The Burrow" - I always thought it was Ginny's hair although Harry didn't realize that at the moment. This would count as a "loved one". The same goes for a third thing smelled by Hermione - I think she didn't finish because she didn't want to admit her feelings for Ron. But I have no citation at hand to support my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to what the person truly loves, so technically is possible to smell a relative or a loved one if its what attracts you more.

> It has a different aroma for everyone who smells it, **reminding each person of the things that they find most attractive, even if the person doesn't acknowledge or is unaware of their fondness for the object of their affection** themselves

[Source](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Amortentia)